# OpenGL installation/initialization

Tags: opengl, visual-studio-2012, glut

I am trying to write some openGL code in visual studio 2012. I've looked over the internet to try and get this set up properly, and I can't seem to solve this.

```
#include <gl\GL.h>
#include <gl\GLU.h>
#include <gl\glut.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv){

    glutInit(&argc, argv);

}
```

The glutInit line does not work, saying glutInit is not defined. Can someone please walk me through how to set this up properly in VS 2012? I've done things like this before in 2010, and would really like to just start working on my project.

Comment: Is it finding the headers? (though you'd be better off using almost anything other than glut, IMO).

Comment: supposing I have to use glut for a class...

Comment: I'm fairly sure I haven't linked it properly, but don't know how to go about linking it

Comment: The usual library name is glut32.lib. You'll need to give the compiler the library name and the directory where it's at. The directory will normally be `<glut_dir>\lib\glut` where `<glut_dir>` is wherever you put glut (e.g., `C:\glut-3.7`).

Comment: I've added an answer showing how.

Answer (score 2):

You add the glut directory to the VC++ directories, here:

[image]

Then you need to add the name of the library under the Additional Dependencies:

[image]

Comment: When you say add the glut directory, do you mean glut32.lib directory?